# text-indent for image replacement?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using the following for my top menu `a` links:

```
 #sliding-navigation #filter-regista a  {
   width: 75px;
   height: 29px;
   background: transparent url("images/directors.png") no-repeat 0 0;
   text-indent: -9999px;
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to apply the styles to your `<a>` and not `<li>`

```
#sliding-navigation #filter-regista a {
    background: url("images/directors.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: 101%;
    width: 75px;
}
```

Comment: still not working, sorry was my fault not to add 'a' in my question code, updated the question, same issue tho

Comment: The CSS I posted has some changes. Have you applied those?

Comment: ok actually applied yours and it works, now regardless of the previous missing tag, what's making yours working? I usually used the code i posted

Comment: The `text-indent` property applies to *block and inline-block elements, table cells* only. Your `<a>`-s were *inline*, so it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You're not pointing to the right tag. You should point to your a tags

Comment: still not working, sorry was my fault not to add 'a' in my question code, updated the question, same issue tho

Comment: If you do what Zoltan said, it's going to work... you have to set your a elements to display: block; or display; inline-block; as he suggested to set a width and height to that element. Overflow hidden will ensure that only half of your image will be shown. and text-indent is fine the way you did using -9999px;